# Proving infinite wedge sum of circles isn't first countable

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

Let $\{S_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ be a countable family of circles and $\{p_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$  be a family of points such that $p_i\in S_i$. let $X = \bigcup _{i=1}^\infty S_i/\{p_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ be the topological space obtained from the quotient map $q: \bigcup _{i=1}^\infty S_i\longrightarrow X$ by collapsing all $p_i$ to one point $p\in X$. Show that $X$ is not first countable.

I had this diagonalization idea:
suppose for the sake of contradiction that there's a countable neighbourhood basis $\{U_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ at point $p\in X$.  let $V_{ij}=q^{-1}(U_i)\cap S_j$.

At this point my intuition suggests that $W=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty V_{ii}$ is a saturated open set that satisfies $$\forall i>0(U_i\nsubseteq q(W))$$ thus arriving at a contradiction but all my attempts so far to prove it rigorously have failed.

Any help formalizing my argument will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: For each $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ there is an $r_k>0$ such that

$$B(p_k,r_k)\subseteq q^{-1}[U_k]\;,$$

where $B(x,\epsilon)$ is the usual open ball. For $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $\epsilon_k=\frac12r_k$, and consider the image under $q$ of the saturated open set

$$\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb Z^+}B(p_k,\epsilon_k)\;.$$

Comment: I still don't quite get why the diagonalization is necessary in this solution.

Comment: @Shaul: I don’t know any essentially different way to construct an open nbhd of $p$ that doesn’t contain any of the $U_k$’s.

Comment: Won't $B(p_k,r_k/2)$ work?

Comment: @Shaul: It’s not saturated, and it’s entirely possible that $q^{-1}[q[B(p_k,r_k/2)]]$ does contain some $U_n$ with $n\ne k$.

Comment: I meant $$\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb Z^+}B(p_k,r_k/2)\;.$$. I'm apparently doing something wrong because it works for me on paper. I really want to get it right in my head.

Comment: @Shaul: But what is $r_k$?

Comment: The way you defined it only without using the n index.

Comment: @Shaul: You’ll have to be more explicit, because what I defined required the upper index in order to make sense, so I really don’t know what you mean.

Comment: For each $k$ there's a radius $r_k$ for which $B(p_k,r_k)\subseteq q^{-1}(U_k)$

Comment: @Shaul: You’re right: you’re doing what I thought I’d done when I wrote the answer. I’ve no idea why I threw in that extra complication, which in any case I never used; I’ve fixed it now to say what I meant all along. It’s a good thing that you were persistent!