# Geometric Realization of Finite Dimensional Abstract Simplicial Complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

I am learning the theory of complex. And there are two theorems presented by our teacher:

- Every abstract complex $K$ has its geometric realization.
- Every $n$-dimensional abstract complex $K$ has its geometric realization which can be embedded in $\mathbb R^{2n+1}$.

The proof of first can be found in Munkres's book: *Elements of Algebraic Topology*, and our teacher gave the finite version proof of second. Now I am curious about that

- If $K$ is infinite, then how do we prove the second statement? Is it related to the **Zorn Lemma**?

Any advice is helpful. Thank you.

Comment: You you specify what you mean by an "infinite" abstract simplicial complex.  For example, if you take an uncountable disjoint union of simplexes of positive dimension, it does not have a geometric realization in any $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Comment: @Slade An abstract complex $K$ has finite dimension but has infinite simplicial complex in it.

Comment: My point is that with that definition, the theorem you propose is extremely false.  One could ask whether a _countable_ simplicial complex has a geometric realization in some $\mathbb{R}^N$ (specific or not), but I'm not sure what leads you to believe that a statement like this should be true without some assumptions—have you seen this somewhere, or is it a guess?

Comment: @Slade Is the countable condition essential. We can consider the  zero dimensional complex $\{x\}_{x\in\mathbb Q^c}$. It is a complex in $\mathbb R$

Comment: According to what definition?  It's a set of points, sure, but what mathematician has ever called it a _complex_?  The countable condition is not essential, but for geometric realizations?  $\mathbb{R}^n$ cannot be the uncountable disjoint union of full-dimensional polytopes, which destroys any definitions I'd be comfortable with of a geometric realization of an uncountable abstract complex, but I'm not the one asking questions about it—until you tell me what you think an abstract simplicial complex is, and what you think a geometric realization is, I have no idea what is essential or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second result you mention is totally false for infinite complexes (even countable complexes), at least with the standard definitions.  Indeed, there is a $1$-dimensional countable simplicial complex that does not embed in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $n$.  Namely, take a simplicial complex $K$ that has countably infinitely many edges which all share a vertex $v$.  The geometric realization of $K$ then is not even first-countable (see [Proving infinite wedge sum of circles isn't first countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560989/proving-infinite-wedge-sum-of-circles-isnt-first-countable) for a sketch of the argument).