# Is a bouquet of circles always a CW complex?

Tags: general-topology, cw-complexes

Let $X$ be a cell complex with one $0$-cell and an arbitrary (possibly infinite of any degree) number of $1$-cells which are self-loops to the only $0$-cell. Clearly $X$ is closure-finite (property C in CW). Is the topology of $X$ necessarily coherent with the set of closed cells of $X$ (property W in CW)? That is, is $X$ a CW complex?

Note: If $X$ is first countable, then I can show that being locally finite is equivalent to property W. This result can be used to show, for example, that the closed infinite (countable or uncountable) [broom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_broom) does not have property W. There is a [question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560989/proving-infinite-wedge-sum-of-circles-isnt-first-countable) which states that an infinite bouquet of circles is not first countable, which excludes using this result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't specified the topology on $X$, the answer is no in general. For example, $X$ could be the union of the circles $C_n$ in the Euclidean plane with center at $(1/n,0)$ and radius $1/n$. If we topologize this $X$ as a subspace of the plane, it consists of a single $0$-cell $O$ (the origin) and infinitely many loops $C_n$ at $O$.  But it's not a CW complex; it doesn't have the weak topology. For example, the set consisting of the closed right halves of all the $C_n$'s (i.e. the part of each $C_n$ where $x\geq 1/(2n)$) meets each $C_n$ in a closed set, but its closure contains $O$.

Comment: This space is called the Hawaiian earring. Googling that name will produce lots of information about it.

Comment: Good point. I was thinking about $X$ being a bouquet of circles, so a wedge-sum of circles, but it is missing from the question. Wikipedia states that such $X$ and the Hawaiian earring are not homeomorphic, so this detail changes the question:/ Not sure whether I should add that detail or create a new question...

Comment: Before adding details about which topology you want, check whether those details lead directly to an answer to your question.

Comment: I think that the bouquet of circles and its cells would satisfy property W by construction, by wedge-sum topology, right?